# How to fix: Image background doesn't show up on physical device in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, assets

I'm learning Flutter and I want to display a background image in my app but it's not showing up on the physical device.

I added an image background to the application. It's showing up on Android emulator. But when I use a physical device then there is no image (only white background).

I tried `flutter clean`, `flutter pub get` and then `flutter build apk --release` to create APK file. Then I installed this on the device.

I also tried to use a device with the debugging (debug console doesn't show any errors or warnings).

In both cases, I have a white background.

My `pubspec.yaml` file:

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/images/background.jpg
```

`MyHomePageState` class where I use this image:

```dart
...
          body: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage('assets/images/background.jpg'),
                fit: BoxFit.contain,
              ),
...
```

The output of the `flutter doctor -v` command:

```bsh
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.7.8+hotfix.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.239], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.7.8+hotfix.3 at C:\AndroidFlutter\flutter
    • Framework revision b712a172f9 (3 weeks ago), 2019-07-09 13:14:38 -0700
    • Engine revision 54ad777fd2
    • Dart version 2.4.0


[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\AndroidFlutter
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = C:\AndroidFlutter
    • ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[!] Android Studio (version 3.4)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01)

[√] VS Code (version 1.36.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\Cyber\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.2.0

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • LG V500 • LGV500d21491fe • android-arm • Android 7.1.2 (API 25)
```

Here is my [repository](https://github.com/MadTiger2409/BMI-Flutter-App).

I expected the screen to look like this (and this is from Android emulator):

[image]

but instead, I have a white background (all controls are rendered properly.

Comment: can you post your 'flutter doctor -v' output so we can see that there are no issues with your installation. EDIT I've just been to your github, the image is massive, can you shrink it down test you just aren't seeing the white parts of the image.

Comment: Also worth trying the code here using 'ExactAssetImage' this https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BoxDecoration-class.html

Comment: I updated the question. I can shrink this, give me a minute or two.

Comment: I resized image and changed code to use ExactAssetImage - still no image in the background.

Comment: Very strange, your project works fine for me. This might sound obvious but if you haven't already close Visual Studio Code down and reopen it. Run 'flutter packages get' then do a fresh install of the app on your device

Comment: Still the same result. I will try tomorrow to set up the environment on my laptop and try to compile on it. Maybe it's something with my PC. Android emulator scenario was working correctly on PC in my company. The device scenario is on my personal PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I managed to solve my problem.

There are steps that helped me:

1. Delete local repository.
2. Clone repository from GitHub.
3. Run `flutter upgrade` command to have the newest version of the Flutter framework.
4. Run `flutter run` command to run the application on the connected physical device.

Comment: flutter run did it for me.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution with the following two links;

1. [flutter issues](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/31548)
2. [internet permission](https://java2blog.com/add-internet-permission-in-androidmanifest-android-studio/)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

I have added the above line into the file AndroidManifest.xml under android/app/src/main/